# How to make Microsoft apps use Edge although my default browser is Firefox?

Tags: windows, web-browser

I use Firefox as my default browser on Windows11 but I'd like Edge to be used when I click a link inside Microsoft apps like Teams/Office/OneNote etc. Based on my research, I don't think this is possible via System Settings. Is there an app that could help with this?

Comment: A quick hack could be creating a .bat file that reads the passed argument and launches it with msedge.exe if the URL contains a Microsoft domain, or with firefox.exe if not

Comment: Thanks but my usecase does not begin with a browser. The scenario is that I'm using the desktop version of a Microsoft app and click a link in the text of the document/spreadsheet/slide-deck/note.